# How to redirect all that URLs that ends with “-2” to the same link without "-2"?

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an comparison website based on woocommerce and I have the following problem.

I have 1 product from 2 vendors:

Vendor 1: `https://example.com/lista/ceas-accurist-signature-7220-classic/`

Vendor 2: `https://example.com/lista/ceas-accurist-signature-7220-classic-2/`

Through `.htaccess` I want to 301 redirect all the links that finish in `-2/` to the original one, without `-2/`.

Any idea how I can build the `.htaccess` rule based on that suffix `-2/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule (.*)-2/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any URL that ends in `-2/` is redirected to the same URL without `-2`.

The `$1` (in the *substitution* string) is a backreference to the captured group (the part before the `-2/`) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Comment: Thanks so much mate. It works. Highly appreciate your effort!